# Extending DataContext entities - using InsertOnSubmit(this) inside "child" class

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am extending this DataContext entity, which looks sort'a like this:

```
namespace Entities
{
    public class User
    {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public String Username { get; set; }
    }
}
```

.. Like so:

```
public class User : Entities.User
{
    new public Int32 Id
    {
        get { return base.Id; }
    }


    public void Insert()
    {
        using (var dc = new DataContext())
        {
/*
The "this" keyword should match the type that InsertOnSubmit() expects.
And it does. But I get the following error:

System.NullReferenceException: {"Object reference not set to an instance
of an object."}
*/
            dc.Users.InsertOnSubmit(this); // Exception occurs here

            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the custom User class like so:

```
var u = new User { Username = "Test" };

u.Insert();
```

What I don't get is this: I have instantiated the class, so why am I getting a NullReferenceException?

### Update:

**Extending entity class: overriding a property with an enumerator while still being able to use the "this" keyword on the `Insert`/`Update` and `DeleteOnSubmit` methods on a DataContext instance**

```
enum AccessLevels
{
    Basic,
    Administrator
}


namespace Entities
{
    public class User
    {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public String Username { get; set; }
        public Int32 AccessLevel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How would I extend or alter the above entity class and implement the `AcessLevels` enumerator, replacing the `AccessLevel` property?--this without altering the signature of the entity class, so I'm able to use the "this" keyword on `Insert`/`Update` and `DeleteOnSubmit` methods on a DataContexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re the enum edit (added as a second answer to keep things simple)...

Firstly - is there a direct 1:1 mapping between the enum and the values? For example, if Basic is 7 and Administrator is 12, then:

```
enum AccessLevels
{
    Basic = 7,
    Administrator = 12
}
```

Then change the type of that property in the dbml (via the designer) from int to your (fully-qualified) enum: `Entities.AccessLevel`. LINQ-to-SQL supports enums either as direct integer mappings, or as direct string mappings.

If this isn't possible (more complex scenerios), you can isolate the storage (int) and object-oriented (enum) models; rename the property to `AccessLevelStorage` (or anything else you like), and in a partial class do the mapping:

```
partial class User {
    public AccessLevel AccessLevel {
        get {
            switch(AccessLevelStorage) {
                case 1: return AccessLevelStorage.Foo;
                ... etc
                default: ...throw an exception?
            }
         }
         set {
            switch(value) {
                case AccessLevel.Foo: AccessLevelStorage = 1; break;
                ...etc
                default: ...throw an exception?
            }
         }
}
```

The only caveat here is that LINQ queries will only work against the *storage* properties - not the custom mapped property. If you do your queries at the level that declares the context, you can change the access of the storage property to `internal` - but if you do queries outside of this assembly you'll need to leave is public. You might want to add `[Browsable(false)]` to stop it appearing in UI models, but that is about it.

Comment: Excellent! First option in my case. Thanks a bunch Marc :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't extend LINQ-to-SQL entity types in this way via inheritance - you should instead use a `partial class` to add extra methods to the *existing* generated entity. Because LINQ-to-SQL supports inheritance (for discriminated tables, etc), it expects an **exact** match to a known entity type - not unexpected subclasses.

i.e.

```
namespace Entities {
    partial class User {
        /* your extra method(s) here */
    }
}
```

In the above, this is *combined* with the partial class in the designer.cs to create you type.

The other way to do this (if partial class isn't an option) is via an extension method.

```
static class EntityExtensions {
    public static void SomeMethod(this User user) {...}
}
```

If there are methods common between types, you can do this by declaring an interface, using extension methods *on* that interface, and using partial classes to add the interface to the specific types:

```
namespace Entities {
    partial class User : IFunkyInterface {
        /* interface implementation, if necessary */
    }
}

static class EntityExtensions {
    public static void SomeMethod(this IFunkyInterface obj)
    {...}
}
```

or if you need to know the type:

```
static class EntityExtensions {
    public static void SomeMethod<T>(this T obj)
          where T : class, IFunkyInterface
    {...}
}
```

Comment: Good advice. Only.. I need to override a property of the entity class, which is not possible using partial classes, so I guess I'm forced to do extension methods--only; how can I do that? How can I add specific methods to specific entity classes? Could you update your answer?

Comment: What do you mean "override a property"? There are existing partial methods for most of the common before-change/after-change scenarios. I'll add an example for extension methods.

Comment: Hey Marc. Updated my question. I'd appreciate your take on it.